# exporting to word file( *.doc ) in php

Tags: php, export, documentation-generation

i have one php page which prints some information. Information is a table with some values dynamicaylly printed in table cells.Now instead of sending this page to browser i want the page to be exported to a word file.How can i do it?

In short i have a page `A.php` . A.php contains a link to `B.php`. When the link on `A.php` is clicked i want the file to be exported to ms word file `(*.doc).`The browser should display the box which says save as or open.

I used to to above thing is jsp by changing some headers. But how can i achieve the above thing in php?

Answer (score 2):

google "php microsoft word"

second result:http://forums.devarticles.com/php-development-48/can-php-write-or-read-microsoft-word-files-12011.html

second post:

### https://www.php.net/com

Answer (score 0):

A library to do this specifically, PHPWord.

Give this a shot.